# Azure user not able to modify their own profile

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We are using rest Apis to create new users on azure.

User get created successfully. However, when we acquire the token for the newly created users and try to call update user rest api. It gives insufficient priviledges.

Kindly help in finding out what exact roles and permission that are required for executing update user and change password and reset password rest api(on azure).

Also, kindly guide how to set them up in initial create user call or subsequent rest api calls () ?

Comment: Basically I am looking for set of permission to be assigned to new user by which user can edit his own profile only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is likely that the new user you have created as not consented to the permissions required for your app to update their profile.

A user does have the permission to change their own profile settings, but they need to delegate those permissions to any application wishing to do it on their behalf. If you are programmatically creating a user, and then trying to immediately doing some sort of passive sign-in with that user, you might be skipping the consent prompt required for the application to gain access to actually make changes to the user's account.

One solution is to make sure you have the right permissions selected for the operations ([Delegated Permissions: User.ReadWrite](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions)), and then make sure the new user goes through an active authentication experience where they will see a consent screen for this permission. At that point, the user token will enable you to change and update their profile.

The other solution is to create an application that has access to update all users in a directory, without needing any users to be sign in. The permission required to do this is [Application Permissions: User.ReadWrite.All](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions). Initially, a Tenant Administrator will need to consent to this application to give access to the application to read and write information for all users in that directory. However, after that initial consent is given, this application will always be able to call APIs to update all users in that directory, all without any user authentication. This option makes the most sense if you are planning on programmatically creating and updating user accounts.

Let me know if this helps.